# '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I get a json form POSTMAN and created a file that contains the classes and then with cubit and dio I did the get method also with bloc Provider I called the get method in the main and this error shows up
'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

And this is how I handle response:

```
void getFavoritesData() {
     DioHelper.getdata(
       url: FAV,
       token: token,
     ).then((value) {
       favoritesModel = FavoritesModel.fromJson(value.data);       
       print(favoritesModel?.status);
       printFullText(value.data);
       emit(ShopAppGetFavoritesSuccesState());
     }).catchError((error) {
       emit(ShopAppGetFavouritesFailedState());
       print(
           'Error in bringing data from API in the Favorites ${error.toString()}');
     });   }
```

I checked from all the vaiables and data types and it all correct

```
class FavoritesModel
{
  late bool status;
  late Data data;

  FavoritesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  {
    status = json['status'];
    data = (json['data'] != null ?  Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null)!;
  }
}

class Data
{
 late int currentPage;
 late List<FavoritesData> data=[];
 late String firstPageUrl;
 late int from;
 late int lastPage;
 late String lastPageUrl;
 late String path;
 late int perPage;
 late int to;
 late int total;


  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  {
    currentPage = json['current_page'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      json['data'].forEach((element) {
        data.add(FavoritesData.fromJson(element));
      });
    }
    firstPageUrl = json['first_page_url'];
    from = json['from'];
    lastPage = json['last_page'];
    lastPageUrl = json['last_page_url'];
    path = json['path'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    to = json['to'];
    total = json['total'];
  }


}

class FavoritesData {
  late int id;
  late Product product;

  FavoritesData({required this.id,required this.product});

  FavoritesData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    product =
    (json['product'] != null ?  Product.fromJson(json['product']) : null)!;
  }


}

class Product {
  late int id;
  late dynamic price;
  late dynamic oldPrice;
  late int discount;
  late String image;
  late String name;
  late String description;



  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    price = json['price'];
    oldPrice = json['old_price'];
    discount = json['discount'];
    image = json['image'];
    name = json['name'];
    description = json['description'];
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you include how you are handling response

Comment: ```void getFavoritesData() {
    DioHelper.getdata(
      url: FAV,
      token: token,
    ).then((value) {
      favoritesModel = FavoritesModel.fromJson(value.data);
      print(favoritesModel?.status);
      printFullText(value.data);
      emit(ShopAppGetFavoritesSuccesState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      emit(ShopAppGetFavouritesFailedState());
      print(
          'Error in bringing data from API in the Favorites ${error.toString()}');
    });
  }```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this below:

```
class Data
{
 final int currentPage;

 Data({required this.currentPage});
  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  {
    return Data(currentPage :json['current_page']);
    
  }

}
```

Comment: add currentpage and the others or only this variable

Comment: Do as I say not as I do.
Follow the pattern.

Comment: so i take it instead of the class data i have right